# Нет возможности выбрать Hibernate в Add framework support

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

Решил подключить приложение к БД, используя Hibernate, но у меня нет возможности его добавить, в Add framework support я могу добавить только Groovy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-то сталкивался и знает как это решить?

Answer (score 0):

Так можно добавлять только если у вас Ultimate версия Idea. У вас, судя по всему, Community версия. Поэтому так не выйдет. Вам придется либо переходить на Ultimate версию, либо добавлять hibernate как зависимость, например:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

и сделать настройку Hibernate отдельным файлом с конфигурацией.
Ну и можно пользоваться.